# Issue with Nextjs SSR on Link Previews

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using Nextjs SSR using `getServerSideProps` that fetch data from the server and return to the main Component for Render, Rendering View Works fine getting expected data and view, The Link preview was working and than stops automatically.

I have used all the meta tags for the Link preview like this,

```
<Head>
        <title>{title}-Snapi</title>
        <meta name='twitter:card' content='summary_large_image' />
        <meta name='twitter:title' content={title} />
        <meta
          name='twitter:description'
          content={description.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, '')}
        />
        <meta name='twitter:site' content='@yourusername' />
        <meta name='twitter:image' content={imageUrl} />
        <meta name='twitter:creator' content={creatorName} />

        <meta property='og:url' content={ogUrl} key='ogurl' />
        <meta property='og:image' content={imageUrl} key='ogimage' />
        <meta property='og:site_name' content='SNAPI' key='ogsitename' />
        <meta property='og:title' content={title} key='ogtitle' />
        <meta
          property='og:description'
          content={description.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, '')}
          key='ogdesc'
        />

        <meta name='apple-itunes-app' content='app-id=284882215' />

        <meta name='google-play-app' content='app-id=com.facebook.katana' />
        <meta
          name='msApplication-ID'
          content='appId'
        />
        <meta
          name='msApplication-PackageFamilyName'
          content='facebook_9wzdncrfhv5g'
        />
        <meta name='kindle-fire-app' content='id' />

        <link
          rel='apple-touch-icon'
          href='myUrl'
        ></link>
        <link
          rel='android-touch-icon'
          href='myUrl'
        ></link>
        <link
          rel='windows-touch-icon'
          href='myUrl'
        ></link>
      </Head>
```

While Testing the Link Preview locally i'm using a Third Party Extenstion Social Share Preview, The extention shows the expected results as this link will show the image title and description image is attached. This has been also tested from my prod app url and ngrok nothing works.

Once i test my url on https://socialsharepreview.com/ it shows nothing found as meta tags and SSR is not working.
[image]

Comment: how is the website supposed to connect to your localhost? You need to expose your site to the internet, either by deploying on a server (ip forwarding if you can) or use a tunnelling service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Comment: Yes, it has been tested from my deployed version and using ngrok, same results